# Add every element in array to template literal

Tags: javascript, css

I have a function called `calculateElementHeight` that can take in an array of offsets. I basically want to grab every element in the array of offsets and use it to return a template literal string from the function.

```
const calculateElementHeight = (offsets: string[]) => {
// some code that allows me to grab every element in the offsets array and put a '-' in front of it

// return `calc(100vh - all the elements in offset array)`

}
```

So for example, if the offset array in put was `['10px', '20px', '30px']`, the `calculateElementHeight` function should return `calc(100vh - 10px - 20px - 30px)`. Note: the offset array can contain different units (i.e. `['10px' '20%', '30em']`) so this has to be taken into account.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix all the offsets with `" - "`, then join. Works when the list is empty as well.

```js
const calculateElementHeight = (offsets) => {
    return `calc(100vh${offsets.map((offset) => " - " + offset).join("")})`;
};

console.log(calculateElementHeight(["10px", "20px", "30px"]));
```

Answer (score 3):

**A late to the party answer**

Unlike other answers, this solution also handles null and undefined input. Instead of using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to append a hyphen to each element, it simply creates a new array using "100vh" as the first element.

```
`calc(${[minuend, ...offsets||[]].join(" - ")})`
```

[Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) could also be used to produce the same output:

```
`calc(${[minuend].concat(offsets||[]).join(" - ")})`;
```

*( minuend: a quantity or number from which another is to be subtracted. )*

**Snippet**

```js
const calculateElementHeight = (offsets, minuend = "100vh") => 
    `calc(${[minuend, ...offsets||[]].join(" - ")})`;
    
 
console.log(calculateElementHeight(['10px', '20px', '30px']));
console.log(calculateElementHeight(['10px', '20%', '3em'], '90vh'));
console.log(calculateElementHeight([]));
console.log(calculateElementHeight(null));
console.log(calculateElementHeight());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with a `-` delimiter.

```js
const calculateElementHeight = (offset) => {
  return `calc(100vh - ${offset.join(' - ')})`;
}

const offset = ['10px', '20px', '30px'];

console.log(calculateElementHeight(offset));
```

Comment: In this case, you have a problem with an empty list.
You need to check the offset length and use or not '-' after `100vh` (`${offset.length > 0 ? '-' : ''}`)

Comment: What empty list @FedeG

Comment: if the offset list is empty, try `console.log(calculateElementHeight([]));`

Answer (score 1):

What is the virtue of just adding each item to the calc - surley you want to sum all the px values and use the total as the amount to be substracted from 100vh?

```js
const calculateElementHeight = (offsetArr) => {
  const totalOffset = offsetArr.reduce((partialOffset, a) => partialOffset + parseInt(a.split('px')[0], 10), 0);
  return `calc(100vh - ${totalOffset}px)`;
}

const offsets = ['10px', '20px', '30px'];

console.log(calculateElementHeight (offsets)); // gives calc(100vh - 60px)
```

Alternatively - just pass an array of numbers to the function to prevent the need for the split and parseInt().

```
const calculateElementHeight = (offsetArr) => {
      const totalOffset = offsetArr.reduce((partialOffset, a) => partialOffset + a), 0);
      return `calc(100vh - ${totalOffset}px)`;
    }

const offsets = [10, 20, 30];

console.log(calculateElementHeight (offsets)); // gives calc(100vh - 60px)
```

Comment: I don't think this accounts for variations in units. For example, if  my offset array looks like this: ['10px', '10%', '10em'], that would not get the expected result.

Comment: @Jevon, you - and those trying to help - would benefit from information such as that being in the question itself (not hidden in a comment to an answer); can you edit your question to include that and any other relevant information where it can be seen?